# How to install the google play lens on 13.04

Tags: 13.04, apt, updates, ppa, lenses

I've tried following the instructions from,

```
 "http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/new-lens-lets-you-search-google-play-from-the-         unity-dash".
```

The first command,

```
 "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:abhshk-btra/rotatingcanvas"
```

adds the repository and returns successfully.

The second command,

```
 "sudo apt-get update"
```

fails with,

"W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/abhshk-btra/rotatingcanvas/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."

I understand the failure easily enough, there are no files for 'raring'. How to proceed from here? Wait for the ppa to be updated, or is there another way to get the lens installed?

Thank you for taking the time to look at this,

Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download and install the lens directly.
Download [googleplaylens_12.11_all.deb from Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Eabhshk-btra/+archive/rotatingcanvas/+files/googleplaylens_12.11_all.deb)

and install it by open a terminal in the folder you downloaded it in and do a:

```
sudo dpkg -i googleplaylens_12.11_all.deb
```

After that you might have missing dependencies, so do a:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to install missing dependencies. Remember that the package won't get updated itself by this way. When there is an update, you'll have to download the new .deb file and install it the same way.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Thanks so much for your help and patience (After reading your reply I looked at the page I listed with the original question again and saw the direct download link!) I hate having public blonde moments. Risking another blonde moment, Do I close this question now that it's been answered?

Comment: Glad, I could help. If this answered your question, you click on the tick on the left next to the post.